# Acceleration proportional to the position

Tags: forces, kinematics, velocity

Question :

if $s^2$ is a quadratic function of $t$, prove that the acceleration varies
inversely as $s^3$.

---

So we have that

$$
s^2 = at^2 + bt + c
$$

And want to show that

$$
a = c s^{-3}
$$

---

If $s^2 = at^2 + bt + c$ then $v = 2s = 2at + b$

Which also means that $v = 2 \sqrt{at^2 + bt + c}$

Then acceleration is

$$
\frac{dv}{dt} = \left( at^2 + bt + c \right)^{-1/2}(2at + b) 
$$

Or

$$
a =
\frac{
(2at + b) 
}{
\left( at^2 + bt + c \right)^{1/2}
}
$$

Subbing in $s$ gives

$$
a =
\frac{
(2at + b) 
}{
\left( s^2 \right)^{1/2}
}
$$

Or

$$
a =
\frac{
(2at + b) 
}{
s
}
$$

But $v = (2at + b) = 2s$ , so

$$a =\frac{v}{s} =\frac{2s}{s}=2
$$

So $a = 2$?

---

which is clearly wrong, but I'm not sure where or why.

---

ans:

We have

$$
s^2 = \alpha t^2 + \beta t + \gamma
$$

Differentiating this we get

$$
2s \frac{ds}{dt}  = 2 \alpha t + \beta
$$

Using that $v =  \frac{ds}{dt}$ this means

$$
2s v  = 2 \alpha t + \beta
$$

Dividing through by $2s$ gives an expression for $v$ as

$$
v =
\frac{2\alpha t + \beta}{2s}
$$

Using the quotient rule to differentiate velocity and find acceleration gives

$$
a = 
\frac{
  (2 \alpha)(2 s)
  -
  2v (2\alpha t + \beta)
}{
  4 s^2
}
$$

If we sub in $v = \frac{2\alpha t + \beta}{2s}$ to the above we get

$$
a = 
\frac{
  (2 \alpha)(2 s)
  -
  2
  \left(
\frac{2\alpha t + \beta}{2s}
  \right)
  (2\alpha t + \beta)
}{
  4 s^2
}
$$

Which gives

$$
a = 
\frac{
  (2 \alpha)(2 s)
  -
  \left(
\frac{1}{s}
  \right)
  (2\alpha t + \beta)^2
}{
  4 s^2
}
$$

Combining terms gives

$$
a = 
\frac{
  4 \alpha s
  -
  \left(
    \frac{
  (2\alpha t + \beta)^2
      }{s}
  \right)
}{
  4 s^2
}
$$

$$
a = 
\frac{
    \frac{
  4 \alpha s^2
  -
  (2\alpha t + \beta)^2
}
{s}
}{
  4 s^2
}
$$

Which reduces to

$$
a = 
\frac{
  4 \alpha s^2
  -
  (2\alpha t + \beta )^2
}
{
  4 s^3
}
$$

From here we can sub in $s = \sqrt{\alpha t^2 + \beta t + \gamma}$ and expanding
the terms gives

$$
a = 
\frac{
  4\alpha^2 t^2 + 4 \alpha \beta t + 4 \alpha \gamma
  -
  4\alpha^2 t^2 - 4\alpha \beta t - \beta^2
}
{
  4 s^3
}
$$

Simplifying to:

$$
a = 
\frac{
  4 \alpha \gamma
  - \beta^2
}
{
  4 s^3
}
$$

Which proves that the acceleration varies inversely as $s^3$ as needed.

Comment: $v=\frac{ds}{dt}$, not what you wrote.

Comment: @DamianSowinski ah - I have got acceleration where I should have velocity, it seems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So we have that
>
> $$s^2 = at^2 + bt + c$$

For fun, try a more general approach.  Let $$s = \sqrt{f(t)} \rightarrow \dot s = \frac{\dot f(t)}{2\sqrt{f(t)}} \rightarrow \ddot s = \frac{\ddot f(t)}{2\sqrt{f(t)}}-\frac{\dot f(t)^2}{4f(t)^{3/2}} = \frac{f(t)\ddot f(t)-\frac{1}{2}\dot f(t)^2}{2f(t)^{3/2}}$$

Recognize that $f(t)^{3/2} = s^3$ and then write

$$\ddot s =  \frac{f(t)\ddot f(t) - \frac{1}{2}\dot f(t)^2}{2s^3}$$

So we seek a function $f(t)$ such that the numerator is a constant

$$f(t)\ddot f(t) - \frac{1}{2}\dot f(t)^2 = K$$

Certainly, $f(t) = kt$ solves this differential equation and then check that

$$s = \sqrt{kt} \rightarrow \dot s = \frac{k}{2\sqrt{kt}}\rightarrow \ddot s = -\frac{k^2}{4(kt)^{3/2}} = -\frac{k^2}{4s^3}$$

as desired.  Let's see if a quadratic works

$$f(t) = at^2 + bt + c \rightarrow \dot f = 2at + b \rightarrow \ddot f = 2a$$

Plug these in to the differential equation

$$(at^2 + bt + c)(2a) - \frac{1}{2}(2at + b)^2 = 2ac - \frac{b^2}{2} = K$$

and see that a quadratic is also a solution.  Let's check

$$s = \sqrt{at^2 + bt + c} \rightarrow \dot s = \frac{2at + b}{2\sqrt{at^2 + bt + c}} \rightarrow \ddot s = \frac{4ac -b^2}{4\sqrt{at^2 + bt + c}} = \frac{4ac -b^2}{4s^3}$$

as desired.

Answer (score 1):

After you differentiate displacement ..
You will get 
2sv= 2at+b 
Here v represents the velocity.
Thus, 
v= 2at+b/2s 
Differentiating velocity wrt time we will get acceleration. 
We can use quotient rule for differentiating RHS .
Then we simple solve and simplify it giving us.
 a = 4ac-b^2/2s^3
Hence proved

Comment: They've given it as $s = $ displacement, so that I would have $velocity = (1/2)(at^2 + bt + c)^{-1/2}(2at + b) $ wouldn't I?

Comment: Don't put the value of displacement just yet.. Leave it as s then differentiation becomes easier

Comment: Ok thanks - but then I have that $v = \frac{2at + b}{2s}$ giving $a = \frac{2a(2s) - (2at + b)(2)}{4s^2}$, so I'm not sure what I've missed there

Comment: You did not take the LCM of the numerator properly. It would be 4s^2a

Comment: I don't follow, you're using LCM = lowest common multiple? And you're saying that it would be 4 * s^{2a} , ? It's hard to understand what you're mean as you're using no parenthesis in your expressions for operation orders

Comment: Forget about the LCM part. In the numerator it would be 4as^2- (2at+b)^2/4s^2

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57891/discussion-between-baxx-and-lakshya-gupta).

Answer (score 1):

You have $s(t)=\sqrt{at^2+bt+c}$. Now calculate $d^2s/dt^2$ and you will get the result after substituting $\sqrt{at^2+bt+c}=s$ back.